# get left joined objects in join command in linq

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, join, resultset

I have 2 classes for examle:StudentClass and SelectedLessonClass.

```
StudentClass{
 studentId,
 name,
 family}
SelectedLessonClass{
 studentId,
 lessonId}
```

I need information of students that select lesson with lessonId=12;

I use join command:

```
students=students.join(selectedLessons.where(sl=>sl.lessonId==12).tolist(),st=>st.studentId,sl=>sl.studentId,.....)
```

Please Guide me,what things must I fill instead of ..... ?

Thanks

Comment: Clarify what's being "left joined" in this situation. What's some sample input and output you'd hope to see from your query?

Comment: What is `students`, what is `selectedLessons`, what is `join`, `where`, `tolist`, what do the actual classes look like? Please post *working* code as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let say you have `listStudents` and `listLessons` you can try something like this (`result` is the list of students that match your criteria):

```cs
var result = from s in listStudents
             join l in listLessons
             on s.studentId equals l.studentId
             where l.lessonId=12
             select s;
```

Comment: In the subject the OP talks about a left join, you're right, but in the details the OP explicitly writes to get only students some lessonId selected

Comment: Thank you,join command work with IENumerable but i have List.